# How to display objects with sound sequentially, preferably with timing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Xcode 5, iOS 7

I'm trying to create/display several objects sequentially, with sound, and preferably with some specified timing.

For example, I'd like to create and display 10 labels.
- Each time a label is created, play a sound.
- Control the display of the label (i.e. animation block for timing)
- Create the next label only after the previous one has been created, sound played, and displayed. Preferably insert a delay between labels.

What I have now is a For Loop which calls
  1: Method A - instantiate the label
  2: Method A calls Method B which contains an animation block to a)play the sound then b)animate the display

My problem is that all 10 labels appear so fast that it doesn't look sequential and I only hear the sound once.

How can I chain these together and control the display and timing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using SpriteKit, then this is probably close to what you are looking for:

```
-(void)managerMethod
{
    float timeBetweenEvents = 3.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        NSObject *someObjectCreatedHere;
        [self performSelector:@selector(doSomethingBasedOnThisObject:) withObject:someObjectCreatedHere afterDelay:(i * timeBetweenEvents)];
    }
}

-(void)doSomethingBasedOnThisObject:(NSObject*)thisObject{
    //do stuff to thisObject
    //load stuff from thisObject
    //etc
}
```

Comment: CH - nope, doesn't work. The loop executes to 10, stacking up the 'performSelectors'. Basically the same problem I'm already having.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but they would be executed after different delays, which is what you asked for, I think. But I'm writing the code blind, so may not be remembering usages. But with my simple example, the 10th method should execute 30 seconds later?

Comment: CH - performSelector does not delay the For loop from continuing to execute - it's just a delay before calling the method(selector). So all the performSelector calls are immediately stacked up resulting in the same issue I'm already having. I need sequential occurrences so that the loop works like: i=0->makeObj, when done, increment i and continue...repeat.

Comment: That's actually not how `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay: works`. You'll get 10 calls to the doSomethingBasedOnThisObjectMethod, spread 3 seconds apart from one another. So do anything you want in that method and you're golden. If you need something other than that, I'd specify it in your question. Obviously there's dozens of different ways you could do this, but with limited info, this is by far the simplest and most streamlined.

Comment: Sorry - my fault! I misread your code and didn't see "i * timeBetweenEvents". Got it now. Thanks.